# How to populate the has_many :through model table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**My Models:**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :directors
  has_many :vips, :through => :directors
end

class Vip < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :organization
    has_many :directors
    has_many :events, :through => :directors
end

class Director < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vip
  belongs_to :event
end
```

**My New Event form:**

```
<%= form_for [@organization, @event] do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :when %>
        <%= f.date_select :when %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :vip %>
        <%= f.select :vip_id, options_for_select(@organization.vips.all.map {|v| [v.name, v.id]}) %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**And my Events Controller:**

```
    def new
        @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
        @event = @organization.events.new
        @director = Director.new
    end

    def create
        @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
        @event = @organization.events.build(event_params)

        if @event.save 
            redirect_to organization_path(@organization)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

So, my Vips are created earlier in the process and sit in the vips table. When I submit the new event form, I get a new entry to my events table just fine. **What I want to do** is have my directors table be populated with a new entry when I submit the new events form. The directors table would need the event_id of the event I just created, and the vip_id from the select tag in the form.

I thought about adding this to the create action

```
def create  
    @director = Director.new

    if @event.save
      redirect_to organization_path(@organization)
      @director.vip_id = @event.vip_id
      @director.event_id = @event.id
```

But that didn't create an entry into the director table. Is there a way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @director.vip_id = @event.vip_id
  @director.event_id = @event.id
```

So, you have these two assignments, `@director.event_id = @event.id` this one is fine because you just created the event and you have the `@event.id`.

But, the first one won't work. Looking at your Model associations, `@event` does not have a `vip_id`, so you can't call `@event.vip_id`. You have to go to the `vip` through the `organization`, something like:

`@event.organization.vips.first.vip_id`

or, `@event.vips.first.vip_id` this would work too as you have `:through => :directors` association.

These two are the only way I see to get a valid `vip_id` corresponding to the event. Although, this will only get the first `vip_id` or you can specify some criteria in a `where` clause to get a particular `vip_id` for that event.

If that works for you, good. Otherwise, you may have to re-think your associations among the models.